# Como editar os itens do ListView em tempo de execução (runtime)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Olhá Makers, eu criei uma ListView pelo Design e precisava editar a posição e tamanho dos texto em tempo de execução, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso? 
No caso os itens que vou editar da ListView são "Text"

Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode usar o evento OnUpdateObjects para alterar, por exemplo: ao redimencionar a tela.

Answer (score 0):

Editar o tamanho dos textos até entendo, mas "editar posição"? O que significa exatamente "editar posição"?

Para editar o tamanho dos textos você pode usar a função SubString, conforme acrescentei abaixo no exemplo do Help:

```
var
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Adicionando itens
  for I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Text := IntToStr(I) + ' Item inserido';
  end;

  // Editando itens
  for I := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count -1 do
  begin
    // Remove a palavra "inserido"
    ListView1.Items[i].Text := ListView1.Items[i].Text.Substring(0, 7);
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o evento OnUpdateObjects para alterar, por exemplo: ao redimencionar a tela.
E usar o     `txt.PlaceOffset.X` e     `txt.PlaceOffset.Y`

```
OnUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem) 
var
  txt: TListItemText;
begin
  with AItem do
  begin

    txt := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('txtLinha1'));
    txt.Width := lstSelecao.Width-8;
  end;
end;
```